# ignore new lines in vimdiff output

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I know that I can ignore white space in vimdiff by `se diffopt+=iwhte`

but I also want to ignore newline character in vimdiff. How can I do it?

e.g.

> > if (a>b){
> >     bar()`

would not be shown diff with

> > if(a>b){bar()

Thanks,

Comment: Edited:- I want to ignore new line character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To really omit the added lines, you will have to write a custom diff function, cp. `:help diff-diffexpr`.

If you just don't want to see the added lines (because they're too visually distracting), you can modify the `DiffAdd` highlight group to show white-on-white (or black-on-black in the console) text (or any other low-contrast coloring, in a similar way:

```
:highlight DiffAdd ctermfg=black ctermbg=NONE guifg=bg guibg=NONE
```

Comment: @ravi: So, you've clarified that you don't want to ignore added lines, just the newline character. My first part of the answer still stands: You need to find a diff tool that supports this. Note that such an implementation may be slower than a vanilla diff, because it also has to take joined lines into account.